# problem with launching application from other os on a multi boot system

Tags: windows, firefox

What do I do so that I could launch firefox on windows 7 if it is installed on windows xp.
I tried going to the drive where it is installed. And launch firefox from there but the firefox that is installed on windows 7 keeps on launching. I even changed the firefox.exe into something different and cleaned the registry using tune up utilites but still don't work. what do I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what do I do

Don't think that Windows XP and Windows 7 can play along like this, imagine that your computer has two **different** operating systems (which it does). You need to install a copy on Windows XP **and** a copy on Windows 7.

Just because you share some hard drives between the two doesn't mean they will place nice.

If you really want to save disk space, you could **consider** installing Firefox to X:\Firefox (where X is a common drive) but unless you keep the configurations in sync (eg if you install an extension it may be installed to X:\Firefox but your user preferences for the extension may be stored in %AppData%\Firefox which is different between your two operating systems) bad things will happen. **I do not recommend this approach**.